# Kentico Nested repeater for grouping similar items

Tags: asp.net, kentico

Anyone with an idea on how to create a nested repeater for kentico? I am trying to achieve a picture gallery with an album such that the album is displayed and a click on an album takes you to the pictures in that album.

I wish I only see a sample as I have only been able create a single repeater creating a picture gallery and not a picture album.

here is my code:

```
    <cms:CMSRepeater ID="pixgallery" runat="server" ClassNames="custom.Gallery"     

        TransformationName="custom.Gallery.Preview" >

           </cms:CMSRepeater>
```

How do I manage this>

Comment: I'd recommend using the hierarchical viewer - nested repeaters are supposed to have some performance issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nested controls are used to display some kind of hierarchy. Please see the [sample](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/controls/cms_listings_and_viewers_using_nested_controls.htm). Or, you can also use [Hierarchical transformations](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/hierarchical_transformations.htm).

Comment: They have updated their site, so your link doesn't work. Here's the correct URL: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Using+hierarchical+transformations